# Shared prefs slow

Tags: android, sharedpreferences

After some days of using shared prefs for my app , I have notified it became slower after each operation and make my app slower .

It only get prefs like :

```
getBooelan
```

and for seting password :

```
Editor edit = prefs.GetEditor();
edit.putboolean("reff", "value");
edit.commit();
```

where is the problem ? what should I do  ?

thanks

Comment: You should post your code, there is not much to say without seeing it.

Comment: for now , the code seems fine . most probably something else is making it slower.

Comment: Try using the Traceview tool to see where your app is spending its time, it might help you figure out what is slowing it down.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is how I use my SharedPreferenceEditor. I am not sure if it would solve your problem or not but have a go at this code and see if this works for you.

```
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = prefs.edit();          
        editor.putBoolean("reff","value");          
        editor.commit();
```

Comment: Shouldn't you be using SharedPreferences.Editor ?

Comment: when you import SharedPreferences, it is not necessary to type   SharedPreferences.Editor

Comment: Oh, okay. Sorry couldn't really help you out. Bdw, I hope in your code, the "b" is just a typo. It's "getBoolean" with a capital "B".

Comment: Thanks , I have wrote that code with my mind ! not coping from Eclispe